# How can I push "bye.jason" which resides in the directory e\XYZ\ABC\XXX\bye.json ? right now i'm getting "no such filer or directory" error message

Tags: cmd, adb

I've also tried adb push 'e\XYZ\ABC\XXX\bye.json' /sdcard and adb push "e\XYZ\ABC\XXX\bye.json" /sdcard

```
@echo.
echo Provisioning to Dev. 
copy "e\XYZ\ABC\XXX\hi.json" "e\XYZ\ABC\XXX\bye.json" /v /y
adb push bye.json /sdcard
@echo complete
Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pushd seemed to solve the problem.

```
@echo.
echo Provisioning to Dev. 
copy "e\XYZ\ABC\XXX\hi.json" "e\XYZ\ABC\XXX\bye.json" /v /y
pushd e\XYZ\ABC\XXX\bye.json
```

adb push bye.json /sdcard
@echo complete
Pause